# Simple webcam/mobile camera app React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, camera, webcam

Im having issues finding the right 'plug and play' solution for a project.
The project is built in React using typescript.
I need a component where a user can take a picture using their webcam, (or mobile device), and upload it. The uploading part is already taken care of.

Is there anybody that can point me in the right direction?
(Im new in react/typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam ? It seems quite 'plug and play' as you require,

```
import React from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";

const WebcamComponent = () => <Webcam />;
```

Comment: Thanks. It took a bit of fiddling but i got it to work